# Prepared statements during connection database

Tags: php, sql, statements

I am trying to make my website protected from sql injections. So I decided to change my code and replace it with prepared statements. I think I made a minor misstake in the code below.

```
<?php
session_start();


$host= 'localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$db='gameforum';


$conn= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if ($password!==$rpassword) {
$_SESSION['err']="Passwords did not match, please try again!";
header("Location: index.php");
    $conn->close();
}
else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, rpassword, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if(!$stmt){
            echo "false";
    }else {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $rpassword, $email);
      if ($stmt->execute === TRUE) {
       $redirectUrl = 'index.php';

   $_SESSION['registrationsuccessful']="Your account was successfully created! You may now log in to your account.";
   header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['alreadyexists']="Username or email already exists!";
header("Location: index.php");
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  }
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
}
    }
```

The problem I am facing now is that I get the message "user already exists" when I try to create an account that do not actually exist. Thanks!

Comment: don't call `$stmt->execute()` twice - instead assign it to a variable and test it for true/false

Answer (score 0):

You have already executed the execute statement.  Remove one of them. Alternatively check for success on only one of the execute statement

Comment: Ok I updated my code above. I got a blank page with "false" now which means that this $stmt = $conn->prepare fails now

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for the problem was the second usage of `$stmt->execute()` - but a few other modifications could be made to the code.

Create the db connection IF the initial logic `if ( $password!==$rpassword )` test succeeds ~ seems pointless otherwise. I would use one session variable for this rather than 3 - it makes it easier to check the values later on other pages perhaps.

Assign the result of the first `$stmt->execute()` to a variable and use that vaiable in further logic tests if needed.

As for error messages - it is fine ( and indeed preferable ) to display verbose error messages for development but never in production - hence removed `$conn->connect_error`.

One other thing, mixing of `procedural` and `object orientated` code is probably not considered good practise - better to stick to one or other ( OO is easier I think )

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['registration_status']="";

    if ( $password!==$rpassword ) {
        $_SESSION['registration_status']="Passwords did not match, please try again!";
        exit( header( "Location: index.php" ) );

    } else {

        $host= 'localhost';
        $user='root';
        $pass='';
        $db='gameforum';


        $conn= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
        if( $conn->connect_error ) die( "Connection failed" );


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `rpassword`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $rpassword, $email);
            $result = $stmt->execute();

            /* use the return value from stmt->execute() */
            $_SESSION['registration_status'] = $result ? "Your account was successfully created! You may now log in to your account." : "Username or email already exists!";

            $stmt->close();
        }

        $conn->close();

        exit( header( "Location: index.php" ) );
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<?php
// if session not start, start now
!session_id() ? session_start() : null;
$mysql_server = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_db = "gameforum";
// connect db connection
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_db);
// chck if connection has error
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s \n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}
// db encoding
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
// when POST happen
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    // convert POST array key as PHP variable
    extract($_POST);
    // if password matched with confirm password
    if ($password === $rpassword) {
        // create insert query with prepare
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, rpassword, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        // if prepare fine, there is no query or mysql error
        if ($stmt) {
            // bind real values
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $rpassword, $email);
            // if query executed
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                // success message & redirect
                $_SESSION['registrationsuccessful'] = "Your account was successfully created! You may now log in to your account.";
                header("Location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                // query error & redirect
                $_SESSION['alreadyexists'] = "There was an error or Username/Email already exists!";
                header("Location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    } else {
        // password matched failed
        $_SESSION['err'] = "Passwords did not match, please try again!";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

***I am not closing connection because, PHP will close all open files and connections at the end of the script.***